# Darboux theorem and the canonical decomposition of a two-fermion wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, fermions, quantum-chemistry

It is a classical theorem in quantum mechanics or quantum chemistry or quantum information that a two-fermion wave function has a beautiful canonical expansion:

$$f(x_1, x_2) = \sum_{j=1}^N \sqrt{p_j} \left( \phi_{2j-1}(x_1)\phi_{2j}(x_2) -\phi_{2j}(x_1)\phi_{2j-1}(x_2) \right).$$

Here $f$ is the wave function which is antisymmetric, i.e., $f(x_1, x_2 ) = - f(x_2, x_1) $. The orbitals $\phi_i$ are the natural orbitals, i.e., eigenstates of the single-particle density matrix. They are orthonormal. The weights  $p_j $ are related to the population in the natural orbitals.

This theorem was first obtained in quantum chemistry by lowdin in 1956 as far as I know. See
http://journals.aps.org/archive/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.101.1730

I discovered it myself when i was studying the best Slater approximation of a fermionic wave function. Its simplicity and beauty surprised me. It is so disappointing that I never found a quantum mechanics textbook mentioning it, although almost every quantum mechanics textbook would mention the two-electron wave function.

Now reading differential geometry, I find the Darboux theorem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem

It seems that Darboux theorem is basically the same stuff as the canonical decomposition above. Is that right? I am not familiar with differential geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Comments to the question (v2):

1. The canonical expansion of the two-fermion wave function seems more related to the [canonical form of antisymmetric real matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Spectral_theory) in the framework of [vector spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) and [linear algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra).
2. The [Darboux' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem) in the framework of [manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) and [differential geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry) (which is a surprisingly potent result) is overkill for the mentioned formula.

The former (1) relies mainly on the properties of skewsymmetry, while the latter theorem (2) also depends deeply on the [Jacobi identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity)$^1$ (JI) for the Poisson bracket.

Phrased in another way: The two-fermion system in the formulation of Ref. 1 possesses no *relevant* analogue of a non-trivial JI, and no arguments  analogous to the proof of Darboux' theorem were used to establish the mentioned formula.

References:

1. P-O. Löwdin and H. Shull, [Phys. Rev. 101 (1956) 1730](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.101.1730).

--

$^1$ The JI is equivalent to the closedness of the symplectic 2-form (if the structure is non-degenerate). See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/431704/11127) related Math.SE post.

Comment: No. If you look at the formula in the Darboux theorem: $\omega = dx_1 \wedge dy_1 + dx_2 \wedge dy_2 + \ldots dx_n \wedge dy_n$, you see it is very similar to the canonical decomposition of the wave function.

Comment: Darboux' theorem is overkill. I updated the answer.

Comment: I agree that Darboux theorem can be an overkill. But, it is instructive to see the link.